# prevent user del files in ipython-notebook environment

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to build ipython-notebook playground environment for colleagues, but it seems can't prevent one people delete another one's file in ipython-notebook. Like,

```
!rm <aaa's file>
```

Could I have some way to prevent this to happen?

**EDIT**: and it also can rm other files...even at other place...

Should I add a new user for ipython-notebook if I want to open it to others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a way to give people read-only access to the notebook, but if you want them to run code, they can do anything that the OS allows them to. So yes, you need to use OS-level security mechanisms, like user accounts or virtual machines.

Comment: Thomas, could you please elaborate on this.  Suppose I have a public notebook server running on  my internal company network.  I know how to password protect the notebooks, but how would I merge OS/linux user accounts with ipython notebooks to prevent rm -rf etc...  Note I don't need anything fancy. I assume the users who are running the notebooks are trusted, I just want to prevent someone doing something stupid, like os.system('rm -rf').  Do I basically need to stand up some type of VM for my notebook server?

Comment: Have a look at [Jupyterhub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub), our project to authenticate system users and run notebooks in their user account. It's fairly young, but it's already seeing some use.